# Copying img element to another div using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, copy

I have a have simple div with a single image. I want to copy that same `img` element to another div.

```
$('.copy').click(function() {
    imageElement = $(this).siblings('img.source')[0];

    item = $('<div class="item">' + imageElement + '</div>');
});
```

I'm getting this:

```
[object HTMLImageElement]
```

Instead of the actual image tag rendering. Any ideas?

Comment: @Cherniv: That gives me something very similar, `[object Object]`. Which I then need to `foo[0]` and we're back at square one.

Answer (score 8):

try this:

```
$("#btnCopy").on("click",function(){
    var $img = $("#firstDiv").children("img").clone();
    $("#secondDiv").append($img);
});
```

working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/GbF7T/

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
$('.copy').click(function() {
    imageElement = $(this).siblings().find('img').eq(0);

 $("div.item").append(imageElement.clone());


 });
```

Comment: Does not work, same as above; this gives me `[object Object]`.

Answer (score 0):

Since your img is within another div, you could use the [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) function.

Something like this:

```
$('.copy').on('click', function(){
    var orig = $(this).children('img');
    var otherDiv = $('#otherDiv');
    otherDiv.html(orig.html());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    $('.copy').click(function() {
         var imageElement = $('#div1').html();
         $('#div2').html(imageElement);
    }
```

If you don't need to replace content in #div2  use "append" or "prepend"  instead of html. 
Eg : $('#div2').prepend(imageElement);

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$(".copy").on("click",function(){
    $("#a_clone").clone().appendTo("#b_clone"); 
});
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 